# Can XSS ever occur in an <img> tag's "src" attribute?

Tags: xss, javascript, css

In a scenario where an attacker has control over the `src` attribute of an `img` HTML tag, they could easily inject a simple JavaScript XSS payload like the following:

```
<img src="javascript:alert(1)">
```

The attacker can not manage to leave the `src` context. For example, the code that causes the above cause could be similar to the following:

```
// Make new image
img = document.createElement('img');
// Set source to hash
img.src = location.hash.substring(1);

// URL is controlled by attacker, so hash can be whatever they want. For example:
// https://ourserver.com/stuff#javascript:alert(1)
```

If you try to run the example scenario above in your own browser, you will probably observe that nothing happens. This is because [JavaScript has apparently been deprecated in the `src` (after IE version 6)](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/124843/255615) and [`style` (after IE version 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25612795/11985743) attributes in `img` tags. The issue with this is that I could not manage to find any explicit rule that says that a browser should not execute JavaScript in this context (as it is a URI, it should be valid).

This all leads me to the big question- is this example code **secure**? Is there any spec that details that in all future browser versions, JavaScript should not execute in `src` or `script` tags? Yes, there are many answers (see above) on Security SE that mention that XSS should not happen in these cases, but is there a *guarantee*?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135513/what-could-an-img-src-xss-do/135518

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! The CSRF exploit usage sounds interesting (`src="/deleteUser"`), but none of the other answers seemed to detail a working example of XSS, or at least the opposite (a guarantee that a browser should NOT execute JS in the `src` context). I tested out the SVG context exploit myself, but all possible JS contexts seem to be [patched](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_image) (such as `onmouseover`, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTML spec states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) that the `src` attribute must point to a valid image resource that is neither paged nor scripted.

> The src attribute must be present, and must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted.
>
> ...
>
> However, these definitions preclude SVG files with script, multipage PDF files, interactive MNG files, HTML documents, plain text documents, and the like.

Whether a future browser complies with this or not is a different story.

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to think that major browsers generally tend to stay within the boundaries of the spec, right?

Comment: @Xiddoc Hopefully they do, but you never know when an overworked dev decides to comment out a line of code because it is causing a weird [heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) and no one notices for a couple of years. Plus, specs can change (although this particular one is not likely to change since it seems security related.)